# How to create an archive without hierarchy

Tags: linux, tar, archiving

I know there are a lot of questions that seems identical, but I haven't found so far my answer.

So let's figure I'm in the current working directory : **/test/**
I would like to add to an archive 'test.tar.gz' which will be in **/test/archive/**
all the files that are contained in **/test/files/** and then delete this directory files/

I tried :

```
tar -cz -C archive -f "test.tar.gz" -C files ./* && rm -rf files
```

But no success.

Any thoughts ?

Thanks ! Nico

Comment: tar zcvf archive/test.tar.gz -C files/ . && rm -f files/*

Answer (score 1):

```
$ tar -zcvf archive/test.tar.gz files
files/
files/1
files/2
files/3

$ tar -zcvf archive/test.tar.gz -C files .
./
./1
./2
./3
```

depending on how you want your tar structured.

Answer (score 0):

A single command like this will work assuming you are already in `/test`

```
(tar -cvf - ./files/* | gzip >./archive/test.tar.gz) && rm -rf files
```

By using `-` we are spewing the output of `tar` command onto `stdout` and then piping it to `gzip` which in turn re-directs its output to `./archive`